# Difficulty fitting with Gaussian distribution

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, optimization, curve-fitting, astropy

I am given two (long) finite sequences (i.e. numpy arrays) `x` and `y` of the same length. There graph is given here:

[image: here].

Array `x` uses the x-axis and is monotonically increasing. My goal is to fit the graph with Gaussian distribution such that the "major peak" is preserved, which looks something like this:

[image: this].

Here is a part of my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy import modeling

fitter = modeling.fitting.LevMarLSQFitter()
model = modeling.models.Gaussian1D(amplitude = np.max(y), mean = y[np.argmax(x)],stddev = 1) #(1)   
fitted_model = fitter(model, x, y)
plt.plot(x,fitted_model(x),linewidth=0.7, color = 'black')

plt.plot(x,y,linewidth=0.1, color = 'black')
plt.savefig('result.png', dpi = 1200)
```

My code results in the following:

[image: the following].

It remains the same if I change the standard deviation in line (1). I figure I must have made some mistakes in line (1) but I have no idea why it is not working. If this is not possible in `astropy`, is there any work arounds?

---

Update:

As it is commented, I think Gaussian may not be the best distribution. I think I am actually looking for something similar to a  [perfusion curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXtoi.png). (In the picture AUC means "area under curve for infinite time" and "mTT" means "mean transit time".) The equation in the picture is not precise. The goal is to make sure the peak is best fitted. The curve does not need to follow the original data very closely as x is close to 0 or infinity. It only needs maintain smoothness and to roughly go down to zero (like the case for Gaussian). I need hints on what kind of function may best satisfy such a demand.

Comment: this code doesn't run. what is x? what is y? you seem to be trying to plot the PDF of y. The x-axis of a PDF is not your x-variable, but instead the `y` variable

Comment: x is the variable for x-axis. y is the variable for y-axis. There is a typo in line (1) which I just fixed. Let x and y be any array of the same length (where x is increasing) and the code should run.

Comment: point is, if you're trying to plot the PDF of y, your `x` variable does not go along the x-axis

Comment: To put it another way, fitting a distribution does not fit a curve to the data

Comment: @PaulH Maybe OP doesn't want to fit a distribution, but just a scaled/moved gaussian curve? But the original curve has too many non-fitting points. Maybe there is a way to give more weight to the points near the center?

Comment: I am really not familiar about the syntax. Maybe I have made some mistakes on that. But my graph looks just fine! I will edit the post tomorrow to give a more detailed explanation.

Comment: What you've drawn in red, your desired graph, is not a Gaussian function. Gaussian functions have a [specific form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function), which is does not fit your data very well. The black curve that you actually get looks to me like it _is_ the best-fitting Gaussian function, in the least-squares sense. Is there a reason you want to fit your data with a Gaussian? Do you expect it to actually follow that shape? If you just want to smooth your data, there are many ways to achieve that.

Comment: I think you are right. I did some more search this morning. I think I am actually looking for something like a perfusion curve (I have updated my post). I thought it is similar to Gaussian so I can fit it using Gaussian. However, I still have no idea how to fit such a curve...

Comment: I don't have the means to try it myself right now, but if you think the perfusion curve could work for you and there isn't a built-in model with a similar-enough profile, you could try implementing it as a [custom model](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.modeling.custom_model.html#astropy.modeling.custom_model), which in general isn't too difficult. You can make AUC and mTT fitted parameters as well, though you will need a way to estimate them to provide good initial values